# Django: How to order a query set for a foreign key by a field of referencing class

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've got two classes:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Part(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        Manufacturer,
        verbose_name=_("Manufacturer"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_("The manufacturer of the part.")
    )
```

Now I ned to make a query that fetches all parts linking to a particual manufacturer. This I've done with `parts = self.part_set.all()`. But Now I need to sort the order. so I assumed the .order_by() could do the trick so in the end I have

```
def get_parts(self):
    return list(self.part_set.all().order_by('name'))
```

Unfortunately this is not sorting correct. So my question is: What is the correct way on sort the list of objects referencing another object by some attribute?

Comment: `self.part_set.order_by('manufacturer__name')` maybe?

Comment: I will need to try it, but I want to sort by Part.name

Comment: `get_parts` is a method inside `Manufacturer`, right? Then maybe `self.part_set.order_by('part__name')` ?

Comment: `self.order_by('part__name').part_set.all()` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always the option of default ordering, via the [`Meta`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/) class on each model. So:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    manufacturer = ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']  # or ['-name'] for descending
```

Now, everytime you get `Part` objects, they'll be sorted by `name` unless an [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) is used in the query.

To come to your question, you can use this:

```
self.part_set.order_by('part__name')
```

but if you have already specified the `ordering` setting of `Meta` inside the `Part` class then you don't have to write it that way. Instead write:

```
self.part_set.order_by('part')
```

and Django will order `Part` objects as per the `Part` `Meta`'s `ordering` setting.

Comment: Actually I see I did it some kind the right way. And by deeper checking I found a data issue with double spaces inside Part.name.